# Determine whether $\sqrt[n]{1+\sqrt[n]{2+\sqrt[n]{3+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n}}}}$ diverges or not

Tags: calculus, limits, nested-radicals

> Determine whether $\{a_n\}$ is convergent or not, where
>   $$a_n:=\sqrt[n]{1+\sqrt[n]{2+\sqrt[n]{3+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n}}}}.$$

At least, we can obtain$$\sqrt[n]{1+\sqrt[n]{2+\sqrt[n]{3+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n}}}}\le\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n}}}}<2,$$which imlies $\{a_n\}$ is bounded. But is it monotonic?

Answer (score 6):

We have
$$
\sqrt[n]{n} \le n,
$$
$$
\sqrt[n]{{n - 1 + \sqrt[n]{n}}} \le \sqrt[n]{{n + \sqrt[n]{n}}} \le \sqrt[n]{{2n}} \le 2n,
$$
$$
\sqrt[n]{{n - 2 + \sqrt[n]{{n - 1 + \sqrt[n]{n}}}}} \le \sqrt[n]{{n + \sqrt[n]{{n - 1 + \sqrt[n]{n}}}}} \le \sqrt[n]{{n + 2n}} \le 3n,
$$
etc. Hence $$
\sqrt[n]{{1 + \sqrt[n]{{2 +  \cdots  + \sqrt[n]{n}}}}} \le \sqrt[n]{{1 + (n - 1)n}} \to 1.
$$
On the other hand $a_n >1$. Hence, the limit is $1$.

Comment: Great answer! It could be slightly improved by saying why the final term goes to 1. At first I didn't believe it, but then I realized $\sqrt[n]{n^2} \sim 1 + 2n^{-1}\log n$.

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting estimate.
When $n\geqslant 2$, $$\sqrt[n]{n}<2,\ \sqrt[n]{n+1}\leqslant 2.$$
$$1\leqslant\sqrt[n]{1+\sqrt[n]{2+\sqrt[n]{3+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n-1+\sqrt[n]{n}}}}}$$
$$\leqslant\sqrt[n]{{\color{red}{(n-1)}}+\sqrt[n]{{\color{red}{(n-1)}}
+\sqrt[n]{{\color{red}{(n-1)}}+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{{\color{red}{(n-1)}}+\sqrt[n]{n}}}}}$$
$$\leqslant\sqrt[n]{(n-1)+\sqrt[n]{(n-1)+\sqrt[n]{(n-1)+\cdots+\sqrt[n]{n+1}}}}$$
$$\leqslant\sqrt[n]{n+1}\to 1\ \text{as}\ n\to \infty.$$